# Using different headers and footer in the same Google document

Tags: google-docs

I've a Google document and it has one header throughout. On a couple of the pages I want to use a different header and footer. For instance:

- pages 1-14 I want **Header + Footer A**
- pages 15-20 I want **Header + Footer B**
- pages 21-30 I want **Header + Footer A**

or for instance:

- page 1 I want NO header or Footer
- pages 2-14 I want **Header + Footer A**

Is this possible to do in one document?

Comment: The question should be rephrased to "Using different header and footer on the *first page* of a Google Document" since you accepted the according answer. Most of us reading the question title hope to find an answer on how to have e.g. page 2 and 3 different. For instance an "Abstract" is on page 2 and has Roman numbering "ii", and page 3 "Table of Contents" has "iii", whereas page 4 starts with page number "1". This is still **not possible** with Google Docs, July 2017. -- And thus Google Docs cannot be used for academic writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of quite recently (24-02-2015) it is possible in Google Documents to have a different header/footer on the first page. Therefore it is only possible to fulfill the second instance you described.

### Quote

Text posted on the Google+ Google Docs page:

```
Headers and Footers - the way you want them
One of your biggest requests (especially those of you who use Docs to write 
academic papers) is to be able to customize how headers and footers appear 
on the first pages of your documents. 

With today’s updates, you can now use different headers and footers on the 
first pages of your documents, which comes in handy for:
> Following academic formatting guidelines (e.g. MLA, CMS, APA)
> Starting page numbering on the second page
> Making a title page without headers or footers

After inserting a header or footer in your document you’ll see a new checkbox
--just tick it and you’ll be able to set a different header and footer on the 
first page.

There’s also a new Insert > Page Number menu that lets you customize how and 
where you start your page numbers--like on the bottom of the second page, 
for example.
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

It might take a while for the feature to be available as it's being rolled out.

### Reference

- https://plus.google.com/112520969446868076741/posts/TovBH2EPCpL

Comment: Thanks, noticed this feature the other day as well, good to finally have it

Answer (score 7):

From the [Google Drive Help documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/86629?hl=en):

> Deleting a single header or footer will delete all headers/footers on each page of your document, just as editing the text in a single header or footer will change the text in the header/footer on each page of the document.

Also, from this [Google Forum Question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/RAlw_h8pYMU), the feature you're asking for, has been requested for a number of people. 
Its last answer is less than a day ago, and this feature hasn't been implemented yet, and there's no information about when or if it's going to be implemented soon.

Comment: This is the correct answer, even though it might not be what the OP wants. Hope he'll accept the answer, though, so the bounty won't go unused.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do make the first page different. But you can make it work by inserting a table at the top or bottom of each page where you want it to be different. It's a workaround, but it works. Just make a sufficient top margin and start your page off with a textbox/table. Copy and paste it on all similar pages and then paste a different one where needed.

Not as easy as Word. But works for now.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I would like to have the header/footer on only one page, but since this feature is not yet added, I have to say that you cannot have a header/footer on only one page, but if you press different header/footer on the first page, you can have a different header/footer for 2-infinity.