# Can I put a certain word/phrase in front of page numbers automatically in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I know that in Google Docs you can automatically put page numbers on each page and it will update them for you when they get moved. Is there a way to do that but also have a certain word in front? I'm writing an MLA paper in Google Docs and MLA requires that each page has in the top-right corner the author's last name followed by the page number. I could do this manually but it would be a pain because upon even the smallest of edits I could potentially have to change multiple page numbers.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the author name in the page header before the page number field.

[image]

Related

- [Using different headers and footer in the same Google document](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/57269/88163)
- [How to move page numbers in a Google Doc?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/105746/88163)

Answer (score 0):

From the menu you will have to insert a `Section brake (next page)` for every different author .

The best way to do this is to -after inserting the Section brake- first insert the page number and then, in front of it, add the author.